# Functions which counts row numbers in a database works only once

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, mysql-connector

I am creating a simple desktop application which connects the user to a database and allows him to do some simple operations (like adding some data, etc.)

I also need to create a window which displays the number of rows in the database. The following function returns the number of rows

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                       host = 'localhost',
                       user = 'root',
                       passwd = 'some_password',
                       database = 'some_database'
                       )

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

def RowCounter():
    query = 'SELECT * FROM `some_database`'
    mycursor.execute(query)
    x = mycursor.fetchall()
    return(len(x))
```

Now I would like to print that result in a window (code posted below is really simplified)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from RowCounter import RowCounter

class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title='Row counter'
        self.left=10
        self.top=10
        self.width=640
        self.height=480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left,self.top,self.width,self.height)

        self.qlabel = QLabel(self)
        self.qlabel.move(10, 100)
        self.qlabel.resize(210, 32)
        self.qlabel.setText('Number of rows in your database:')

        self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox.resize(30, 32)
        self.textbox.move(250, 100)
        self.textbox.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textbox.setVisible(False)

        self.button_refresh = QPushButton('Refresh', self)
        self.button_refresh.clicked.connect(self.on_call)
        self.button_refresh.resize(200,32)
        self.button_refresh.move(210,425)

        self.show()

    def on_call(self):
        self.textbox.setText('')
        self.textbox.setVisible(True)

        x = RowCounter()

        self.textbox.setText(str(x))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The first 'click' works perfectly. Unfortunately after adding something to my database (using the application or just MYSQLWorkbench) and calling the function once again the row numbers do not refresh.

I really wonder what's wrong with my logics or with my code. I will appreciate any help.

EDIT.
I tried the following code and I think something's wrong with the function RowCounter.

```
import mysql.connector
from AddRecord import AddRecord

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                       host = 'localhost',
                       user = 'root',
                       passwd = 'some_password',
                       database = 'some_database'
                       )
def RowCounter():
    mycursor_1 = mydb.cursor()

    query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `pocztowki`'
    mycursor_1.execute(query)

    x = mycursor_1.fetchone()

    mycursor_1.close()
    return(x[0])

print('The amount of rows: ', RowCounter(), '.')

AddRecord(name='Alice', surname='Cooper', other=1, title='Guitar')

print('Everything is O.K.')

print('The amount of rows after calling the function "AddRecord": ', RowCounter(), '.')
```

The function AddRecord works. That's the latest record in my database.
[image: Last row in a database]

That's the output in the terminal
[image: Output]

Comment: Did you debug the RowCounter function to check if it's returning the value updated?

Comment: This is an unnecessarily heavy query. You select and return ah the data simply to count the number of rows. You should do that in the query itself: `SELECT COUNT...`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I changed the code. However it still doesn't work.

Comment: @SamuelTeixeira I checked it and it doesn't return the value updated. I added a few lines of code which print the amount of rows before and after adding a new value -- the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open and close your cursor inside your function.

```
def RowCounter():
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    query = 'SELECT * FROM `some_database`'
    mycursor.execute(query)
    x = mycursor.fetchall()
    mycursor.close()
    return(len(x))
```

Also make sure wherever you insert new data that you commit your updates.

```
mydb.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

i ran in to the exact same problem but am loading all of the information on a QTableWidget
so i use the following code to get all the rows (modified to your needs)

```py
def RowCounter():
    mycursor_1 = mydb.cursor()
    query = 'SELECT * FROM pocztowki'
    mycursor_1.execute(query)
    rows = mycursor_1.fetchall()
    totalrows = mycursor_1.rowcount
    mycursor_1.close()
    return(totalrows)
```

Comment: Did it work for you? Unfortunately your code doesn't work for me :( Still the same problem

Comment: Hmmm kind of late but try all the code in the row counter function outside of the function so you don’t have to use the return statement